# What is the best approach for writing end point for Guest and authorized page

Tags: api, microservices

We are working on social mobile app , its server side logic has based on micro-services architecture and all infrastructure has deployed on amazon api-gateway. Now we are launching a new feature with Guest pages in our app.

Goal is few pages like

1. Post detail (Deployed micro-service A)
2. Profile     (Deployed micro-service B)

has to be public also,

A middle-ware is written that only approves the authorized user and database query is also different for both authorized and public access, Any how response model is same for both conditions.

We need the best opinion, do we need to write a group of separate  API end points those  will also support for above pages and for public pages.

Or Same end point should work for both cases (Authorized and guest)